# Get location address from geocoding api in android

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am going to use Geocoding API to get addresses from coordinates. I set the API key and sha1 in the google console and then make a request just like
this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#ReverseGeocoding) says.

But I get a response including an error, here are my codes:

**LocationApi**:

```
interface LocationApi {

    @GET("json?latlng=35.6731433,51.4204595&key=" + "XXX")
    suspend fun getAddress(): LocationAddress
}
```

**my models**

```
data class LocationAddress(
    @SerializedName("results")
    val results: List<ResultAddress> = emptyList(),
    val error_message: String = "",
    val status: String = ""
)

data class ResultAddress(
    val formatted_address: String = ""
)
```

and finally, provide API :

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideReverseGeoCodingApi(): LocationApi =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(LocationApi::class.java)
```

but here is my response:

> LocationAddress(results=[], error_message=This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 62.212.239.62, with empty referer, status=REQUEST_DENIED)

I don't know what the problem is. The API key and sha1 work because I use google Maps when the app launches and the map API works.

> 

Comment: Did you keep the functionality to ask for `User_location PERMISSION` ?

Comment: I ask for location permissions for google maps and despite having permissions I see the error. However, I think there is no need to have permissions in order to make that request.

Comment: Actually, I am suspicious about how the API realizes the package name and sha1 from my request and maybe I should add them to my request, but I don't know how to figure it out

Comment: Have you follow this guide ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Comment: Yes. As I said Map API works and I enabled geocoding API in the console too but it doesn't work.